# Error in table when adding runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html-table, runatserver

I have a html table in my ASPX page and would like to use it in code-behind for some processing. The table is shown as below:

```
<table class="hovertable" id="tblData">
    <tr>
        <th>ID:</th>
        <td colspan="3" style="font-weight: bold">
            <%= Eval("ID") %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <td><%# Eval("Date", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %></td>
        <th>Amount:</th>
        <td><%# Eval("Amount", "{0:C}") %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, when I add the runat="server" attribute to my table, I am produced with the following error:

```
CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)' has some invalid arguments
```

Any ideas what may be wrong here? Am I missing out anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK guys, I have solved this issue by myself. The problem causing it was because of a `<td>` not having the corresponding `<tr>` element.
It was something like below:

```
<table class="hovertable" id="tblData">
    <tr>
        <th>ID:</th>
        <td colspan="3" style="font-weight: bold">
            <%= Eval("ID") %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <td><%# Eval("Date", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %></td>
        <th>Amount:</th>
        <td><%# Eval("Amount", "{0:C}") %>
    </tr>
    <td colspan='4'>
       Some data....
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: My code was working last night, but not this morning. ??? The `<table id="whatever" runat="server">` should be fine. That is how Microsoft says to do it in [their example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.layouttemplate.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

An html table (which is not a pure asp.net server control) can't contain asp.net server controls. Take a look at this answer:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1524580.aspx/1

In my opinion, you should ask yourself the following question?

Do i need to solve this client or server side?

if your answer is client, you should implement the update logic with Ajax, otherwise you could use the ASP.NET server control and implement it server side.

Comment: Funny thing is that I have tried the same thing in another 2 aspx pages and it works. But not in this particular page.

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer this sounds like "It works on my Machine?".

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer i refer to your "particular page" comment. Maybe this particular page defers from the one your implementing now, i can't see that. Fact is that your trying to use server controls inside a html table and that does not work. I don't intent to be a hardass, just trying to help you out!

Comment: I have checked and surely there is no difference except for the number of rows and columns. All of them use server controls in the html table and is able to be read from code-behind. Just for this page I'm facing issues. I'm totally baffled and frustrated.

Comment: Did you try to use a server-side control and see what happens then?

Comment: I included a Label and still doesnt work. My other page has some labels and works fine though

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17220/discussion-between-rob-angelier-and-confused-programmer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this for the same purpose

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
</asp:Table>
```

What you are trying to do is adding `runat="server"` attribute to a `HTML` control

Comment: An `<asp:Table />` is the WebControls version, whereas `<table runat="server" />` is the HtmlControls version. There are rendering differences between the two.

Comment: I can but I have heaps of tables with lots of rows and columns that would require changing and consume lots of time. Thus I'm putting runat=server to access it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<asp:Labels>` where you need to manipulate data.

```
<table>
<tr><td><asp:Label id="lblRow" runat="server" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Table columns and rows cannot be accessed via code behind if you have `runat="server"` in the  tag because they are pure html.

Another way is to use a `StringBuilder` to create the html table in the code-behind and and `asp:LiteralControl` to output the table.

Comment: Hi, my actual purpose is to render the table's html output and place it in the body of the mail and then send it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Also if we remove the tbody element it will not throw error for td mismatch
Nikhil Mittal

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below elements

```
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```